# Javascript indexOf 2 interchangeable parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, socket.io, chat

I'm using Socket.io, Express, and MongoDB to make a private chat app with auth.
I want to find a room having a string ID **room = socket.id + selectedUser**, where selectedUser it's an id from an array with users.

**How do I find the index position** of the room, having "socket.id && selectedUser" interchangeable?
it works just like .indexOf(X + Y), but I want something like .indexOf(X && Y), result: XY, or YX.

```
[
  '3e3rDZvLGm3debQGAAAA',
  'cIY-he4BJFOxvdF8AAAB',
  '5eac61e5e481853528f4ef115eac61fde481853528f4ef13',
  '3e3rDZvLGm3debQGAAAA'
]

var IndexPosition = Object.keys(this.adapter.rooms).indexOf(socket.id + selectedUser);
```

My pseudo-code idea:
"find the room having **X & Y**, even if synax is **YX** or **XY**"
user 1 - 5eac61e5e481853528f4ef11
user 2 - 5eac61fde481853528f4ef13,

Possible results:
5eac61fde481853528f4ef135eac61e5e481853528f4ef11
 or
5eac61e5e481853528f4ef115eac61fde481853528f4ef13

Comment: What is the issue here? Where are you stuck w.r.t. current code you have already?

Comment: User1 selects user2,
it's created a room:
5eac61e5e481853528f4ef115eac61fde481853528f4ef13
when user 2 selects user 1, it should search the string ID and join.

Now, it just make a new roomID:
5eac61e5e481853528f4ef115eac61fde481853528f4ef13

Principle should be: if the room is, search it, find it, and join.Not make an inverse ID room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this:

1. Check both options.

```js
var keys = Object.keys(this.adapter.rooms);
var index = keys.indexOf(socket.id + selectedUser);
if (index == -1) // not found
    index = keys.indexOf(socket.id + selectedUser);
```

2. Standardize the format. Doing this makes sure the order doesn't affect the end result.

```js
var keys = Object.keys(this.adapter.rooms);
var joinedId = socket.id > selectedUser // this lexicographically compares two strings
    ? socket.id + selectedUser
    : selectedUser + socket.id;
var index = keys.indexOf(joinedId);
```

While I don't know the exact specifics of this, avoid using `Object.keys()` when using a `Map` would be more appropriate. It would also mean you can use `this.adapter.rooms.keys()` instead of the far slower `Object.keys(this.adapter.rooms)`.